# Is the image of a continuous functions always a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be continuous.  Then, for some sufficiently large $M\geq m$, can we always guarantee that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is locally-homeomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^N$, where $N\leq n$?

My intuition is no, since I can imagine a curve crossing itself; but I can't write down an explicit example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&t&\mapsto&\left(\frac{\cos(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)},\frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)}\right).\end{array}$$Its range is a [Lemniscate of Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli), which is not locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ (precisely because of the existence of a self-intersection).

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but doesn’t the self-intersection just mean it’s not an embedded sub manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$? After all, the figure-eight can be immersed into $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What has that to do with the question? The question, when $n=1$, was about whether $f(\Bbb R)$ is locally homeomorphic to some $\Bbb R^N$ and I provided a counter-example: the figure eight is *not* homeomorphic to some $\Bbb R^N$.

Comment: You mention the self-intersection of the lemniscate specifically as the obstruction to being a (topological) manifold, but the lemniscate (as a geometric object) is indeed a manifold (intrinsically). I believe the reason your example works is because your map doesn’t give the nodal point a unique chart to an open in $\mathbb{R}$ along just one of the diagonals through the node.

Comment: @SBRJCT And exactly **where** is the expression “topological manifold” within my answer?

Comment: Let me ask, then: is the point of your counter example that the range of your continuous function, the lemniscate in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is not locally homeomorphic to any $\mathhbb{R}^N$ simply because it has a self-intersection? Forgive me if I seem adversarial; I’m simply trying to verify my understanding. My understanding is that the lemniscate can be given a locally Euclidean structure (i.e., it’s a manifold), though this cannot be done from the given map $f$. Hence the reason for your counterexample.

Comment: Yes, all that I claimed was that the range og my function $f$ is not locally homeomorphic to some $\Bbb R^N$.

Answer (score 4):

Another counterexample with a different issue: Let
$$f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2,(x,y)\mapsto\begin{cases}(x,y)&x<0\\ (x,(1-x)y)&x\in[0,1]\\(x,0)&x>1\end{cases}$$
For $x<1$, the image is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. For $x>1$, it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. At the boundary of both regions, $x=1$, the image can't be locally homeomorphic to either.

Comment: I really like this example!  Thanks!